# symfony input with special css class if errors

Tags: forms, symfony1, input

I would like to know if there is a simple way to add a css class to all input which has an error.

I don't want to use renderError() but just render() method.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Write custom form formatter.
http://kriswallsmith.net/post/144021872/symfony-denote-required-form-fields

Comment: I search in this way but I did not find any solution to change the input. I can change the label but not the input. do you know which method i should overwrite ?

Comment: Widgets have their own renders. Are you sure you absolutely need to set the widget's classname? Or maybe the row's classname will do? For example, `<li class='error'><input.. /></li>`. Then you can match inputs with css like this: `li.error > input`

Comment: <li class='error'><input.. /></li> would be also ok, but I don't know how to do it too :p